# Interraction with map in app mobile

Tags: mobile, geo-location, openstreetmap, google-maps

Is there any possibility to interact with the buildings in Google Maps or another providers like OpenStreetMap, Leaflet, etc?

My goal is to click on a building on the map when you are located next to it, write some information about it in a form for instance, stock it into a BDD and get this data whenever I click again on this building. I'm looking for an interactive map library to use with react-native.

Comment: Are you looking for an app (for what OS?) – or for a library (for what language)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Izzy, i'm looking for an interactive map to use with react-native.

Comment: Thanks Aubouy! So does my edit fit? I'd then clean-up comments. // PS: I know of several ready-to-use Android apps for that. The terminus would be "location based notes" – and they are not limited to locations, but rather bound to coordinates.

Comment: Thanks Izzy, can you be more specific please, if you do have some suggestions like a library map or something equivalent that i can use to generate some user's interactivity with the map, i will be grateful.

Comment: I meant [apps like these](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_locationmemos) (link goes to one of my websites). If you're OK with Google Maps, take a look at [Map Marker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exlyo.mapmarker) which should meet your requirements quite well. For OpenStreetMap, [GeoNotes](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/de.hauke_stieler.geonotes) would be a simple candidate. For something more extensive, there's eg [SMASH](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/eu.hydrologis.smash).

Comment: Hi Izzy, i still not find any solution for my problem, i think is it more difficult to implement that i thought... Here's a link to a website where the map is render data from building when you click on it, it may help to figure out what i was talking to:   https://data.grandlyon.com/jeux-de-donnees/batiments-metropole-lyon/donnees

Comment: Sorry, but I neither speak French nor do I have time to research that for you. Afraid you'll have to wait for someone who knows…